# How to fix : instantiating error in Hibernate validator cdi

Tags: spring, hibernate, jakarta-ee

When using Hibernate validation in Spring MVC, I have an instantiating error in Hibernate validator CDI like shown in the attached image. (I'm using Glassfish Server).

here are my CostumerConstoller and CostumerForm.

```
#CostumerController.java

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import javax.validation.Valid;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/customer")

public class customerController  {

  @RequestMapping("/showCustomerForm")
  public String showStudentForm(Model theModel){

      customer customer = new customer();

      // add customer object to the model
      theModel.addAttribute(customer);

      return "customerForm";
  }

  @RequestMapping("/processCustomerForm")
  public String processCustomerForm( @Valid @ModelAttribute("customer") customer theCustomer, BindingResult theBindingResult ){

      if(theBindingResult.hasErrors()){
          return "customerForm";
      }
      else return "welcomeCustomer";
  }

}
```

```
#CostumerForm.jsp

<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Form</title>
    <style>
        .error{color: red;font-weight: bold;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<form:form action="processCustomerForm" modelAttribute="customer">

    <label for="LastName">Last Name (*) :</label>

    <form:input path="lastName" id="LastName"/>
    <form:errors path="lastName" cssClass="error"/>

    <br><br>

    <label for="FirstName">First Name :</label>

    <form:input path="firstName" id="FirstName"/>

    <br><br>

    <form:button value="Submit" type="submit"> Submit </form:button>

</form:form>

</body>
</html>
```

I have tried using many versions of JARs but nothing work.

[Glassfish Log snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KtRJj.png)

[image]

Comment: Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and rephrase your question. Don't add stacktraces as images those become unreadable and please add the needed code to your question instead of providing a zip people need to download and view.

Comment: As it says in the exception **... ClassNotFoundException:  org.joda.time.ReadableInstant** or one of its depending classes is missing. **org.joda.time.ReadableInstant** could also not be found if one of its imported classes is not available on the Classloader. Check if all dependencies are available during runtime. Maybe hibernate validator declares the dependencies to **joda.time** as provided